# Text file fails to open with ifstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I'm trying to open a file in my program to import some information from it. The relevant part of the code is this one:

```
Airport::Airport(string& apt) {
    ifstream datasid;
    ifstream datastar;
    ICAO = apt;
    if (ICAO == "LEPA"){ //fill map with points and their departure
        datasid.open("LEPASID.txt");
        datastar.open("LEPASTAR.txt");
    }
    else if (ICAO == "LEAL"){ //fill map with points and their departure
        datasid.open("LEALSID.txt");
        datastar.open("LEALSTAR.txt");
    }
    else {
        cout << "El aeropuerto no se encuentra en la base de datos." << endl;
        correct = false;
    }

    if (datasid.fail() or datastar.fail()) cout << "Se ha producido un error al leer los datos del aeropuerto" << endl;
```

When I run the program, I get an error:

> Se ha producido un error al leer los datos del aeropuerto

Meaning that `datasid` or `datastar` failed.

The files are in the same directory as the source files, and I checked that the names are correct.

Comment: What is `apt`? The paths you use in the "LEAL" case seem suspicious. `std::ifstream` does _not_ do globbing.

Comment: Coes ICAO == "LEAL"? Then the path won't work. Set a break point and look.

Comment: @drescherjm I forgot to change the paths in LEAL, but I'm doing the tests with LEPA, so it shouldn't have any effect, right?

Comment: @ravnsgaard  apt is LEPA in the case I'm testing. Yes, I forgot to change the paths in LEAL, but I'm doing the tests with LEPA, so it shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: Try `./LEALSID.txt` etc. I've seen using the current directory cranky about it. Which OS? Try it with a full path also. And drescherjm has something here. Using the `current directory` is often iffy.

Comment: ***The files are in the same directory as the source files*** Maybe that is not the current working directory.

Comment: _checked that the names are correct_ does not necessarily mean that the files are accessible/readable. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail for conditions which can make `fail()` return `true`. That includes more than just "open failed".

Comment: Ok, I don't exactly know what was wrong, but I moved all the program files to a new directory and it's working now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I have run that program in Visual Studio using `main()` and it works fine for me after fixing a few problems:

- Adding the headers: string, fstream, iostream.
- Making ICAO a std::string.
- Adding a return type to the function and putting a "return whatever" at the end.
- Instead of "or" I used ||.
- Making "correct" bool type.
- Adding all the "std::".

Here is my working code. This works for me. Check the differences with yours (I added the `std::couts` to check which `if` is activated). If it still doesn't works, probably the issue is with your variable `ICAO` (it is not LEAL or LEPA), with your `Airport` class, or maybe you don't have the .txt files in the correct directories.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string apt = "LEPA";
    std::ifstream datasid;
    std::ifstream datastar;
    std::string ICAO = apt; 
    if (ICAO == "LEPA") {
        datasid.open("LEPASID.txt");
        datastar.open("LEPASTAR.txt");
        std::cout << "LEPA OK";
    }
    else if (ICAO == "LEAL") { 
        datasid.open("LEALSID.txt");
        datastar.open("LEALSTAR.txt");
        std::cout << "LEAL OK";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "El aeropuerto no se encuentra en la base de datos." << std::endl;
        bool correct = false;
    }

    if (datasid.fail() || datastar.fail()) 
         std::cout << "Se ha producido un error al leer los datos del aeropuerto" 
                   << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, there are few differences with mine, but not too many tho. Anyway it's working now. I changed all the files to a new directory and somehow it works.

Answer (score 0):

I moved all the files, including the sources, executables etc. to a new directory. It's working now. I assume there was some kind of problem with the old directory.